# Blank under footer

Tags: jquery, html

No matter how hard I tried, there's still a blank under the footer of my project.
"Stuck like glue.":(

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/XxB6Y/13/

I know there must be something wrong, but I do not know where. Please, help me.
Thank you so so so much.

Comment: What "Blank" are you talking about ?

Comment: I used browser: GoogleChrome and Safari to test my app, if you use another browser, I do not sure if there is a "blank under the footer" or not. But however, my question has been already answered. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `height:100%;` on a number of elements. Take those off, and the footer space will go away.

In this case, if you need to set the height, try to use pixel units, rather than a percentage.

Comment: ok, I got it, what a precious notice, thank you so much, Benjamin Smith :)